# jQuery: data() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble following the instructions of this problem at codecademy.com. After getting the value stored at 'x' using the data() function, I'm supposed to double it, without using 'var' and then store it at 'y' (using the data() function). I've tried different combinations of 'datafulDiv * 2' to double it, but they've all been wrong. I'm sure this is a simple problem that I'm being very thick about, but if you can help I would be very grateful

```
$('document').ready(function() {



//get the div. 
//do not add var before this object for testing purposes!!
$datafulDiv = $('#dataful');


//get the value stored at 'x'
$datafulDiv.data('x');


//double it and store it at 'y'. again do not use var!



});
```

Comment: hint: what would you do if you *could* declare a var to refer to `$datafulDiv.data('x')` to calculate two times it's current value?

Comment: var = var + var , but I'm still not getting it.

Comment: so then instead of doing `var x = ...; x = x + x`, everywhere you have `x` just write `$datafulDiv.data('x')`. It's the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$datafulDiv.data('y', ($datafulDiv.data('x')*2) );
```

Comment: I may even introduce a `parseInt` just to be safe, but given the sandbox environment probably not necessary.

Comment: `parseInt()` is not necessary.  `jQuery.data()` already converts to a number if the value is all digits.

Comment: Also, FWIW, [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FGlobal_Functions%2FparseInt) would be acceptable (just depends on what X could potentially be).

Comment: @jfriend00: And what if you were _expecting_ a digit and it wasn't one? I was referencing from a sanitation stand point, not because JS can't process "`'2'*2`"

Comment: @BradChristie: If you define a data attribute via `.data()`, it is stored in a JavaScript object bound to that element. It isn't stored as a string. If you load the data attribute from a *real* `data-` attribute, jQuery automatically parses the common data types for you: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L293. There is no reason to parse it twice.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes,but iIt doesn't create a new _attribute_. http://jsfiddle.net/tJ3Jn/4/

Comment: @undefined: Maybe this'll illustrate your point a bit more explicitly? http://jsfiddle.net/tJ3Jn/5/

Comment: @Blender Yes, thanks :), sorry, I didn't want to address you at first.

Comment: @BradChristie - I was referring to the fact that jQuery's `.data()` already converts a numeric value to a number using parseFloat().  See the `dataAttr()` function in the implementation of `.data()` here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js.  So, it's redundant for client code to also try to convert it.  One could test that `.data()` returned a number for safety if desired, but conversion to a number is already done.